# Nested query in Strapi GraphQL

Tags: graphql, strapi

I have a document structured as follows, more or less:

```
post {
  _id
  title
  isPublished
}

user {
  _id
  username
  name
  [posts]
}
```

I know I can query fields like `postConnection` and `userConnection` with the `aggregate` subfield in order to query a count of all objects. But how do I get the total count of all `posts` by a given `user`?

I was able to come up with this:

```
{
  postsConnection(where: {isPublished: true}){
    groupBy{
      author{
        key
        connection{
          aggregate{
            count
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But this returns (expectedly) something like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "postsConnection": {
      "groupBy": {
        "author": [
          {
            "key": "5c9136976238de2cc029b5d3",
            "connection": {
              "aggregate": {
                "count": 5
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "key": "5c99d5d5fcf70010b75c07d5",
            "connection": {
              "aggregate": {
                "count": 3
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, it returns post counts for all authors in an array. What I need is to be able to return the count for **only one specific** `user` and not by `_id` (which is what the `key` field seems to map to) but by another unique field I have in the `users` collection, i.e. `username`.

Is that possible?

Answer (score -1):

Need to pass in a parameter to either the query or the field to return specific data